# How to loop through the list and compare values using ractive js

Tags: javascript, ractivejs

I have a list `{{# {test: . }}}`  and within which I need to have another list
`{{#test:i}}`. So that while iterating I can do a comparison like

```
{{#if test.marks== test[i].marks}}
```

Answer (score 0):

A given reference can only refer to one value at a given location – `test` can't be both the array and members of that array. Try replacing the aliasing block (`{{# {test: .} }}` with a different name (e.g. `{{# {testA: this} }}`).